TabView Cube Transition Doesn't always animate
I have a tabview that is supposed to use a cube transition when the selection changes. Dragging the view to switch the current tab always performs the animation. However in certain cases when clicking to the next tab (sometimes too quickly) the cube transition doesn't take place. This may be because the .task modifier doesn't always execute when the selection changes (task modifier code is meant to invalidate the view for a short period to allow the cube animation). Or there may be another defect that causes the selection to change with no animation. Here is a video of the defect.
Copy Paste-able code (Use Async Image if you don't have KingFisher)
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct StoryViewXX: View {
   @StateObject private var storyData = StoryViewModel()
   var body: some View {
       TabView(selection: $storyData.currentStory) {
           ForEach(storyData.stories) { bundle in
               StoryCardView1(bundle: bundle)
           }
       }
       .background(.black).tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
       .transition(.offset(y: widthOrHeight(width: false) + 50)).environmentObject(storyData)
   }
}

struct StoryCardView1: View {
   @EnvironmentObject private var storyData: StoryViewModel
   var bundle: StoryBundle
   @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
   @State private var timerProgress: CGFloat = 0
   
   var body: some View {
       GeometryReader { proxy in
           let size = proxy.size
           ZStack {
               let activeIndex = min(Int(timerProgress), bundle.stories.count - 1)
               if bundle.stories.indices.contains(activeIndex) {
                   KFImage(URL(string: bundle.stories[activeIndex].imageURL))
                       .resizable()
                       .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                       .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                       .transition(.identity)
               }
           }
           .overlay {
               HStack {
                   Rectangle()
                       .fill(.clear).contentShape(.rect)
                       .onTapGesture {
                           if (timerProgress - 1) < 0 {
                               updateStory(forward: false)
                           } else {
                               timerProgress = CGFloat(Int(timerProgress - 1))
                           }
                       }
                   Rectangle()
                       .fill(.clear).contentShape(.rect)
                       .onTapGesture {
                           if (timerProgress + 1) > CGFloat(bundle.stories.count) {
                               updateStory()
                           } else {
                               timerProgress = CGFloat(Int(timerProgress + 1))
                           }
                       }
               }.padding(.top, 50)
           }
           .overlay(alignment: .top) {
               HStack(spacing: 5) {
                   ForEach(bundle.stories) { story in
                       GeometryReader { proxy in
                           let width = proxy.size.width
                           let index = CGFloat(bundle.stories.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == story.id }) ?? 0)
                           let progress = timerProgress - index
                           let perfectProgress = min(max(progress, 0), 1)
                           
                           Capsule()
                               .fill(.gray.opacity(0.5))
                               .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                                   Capsule()
                                       .fill(.white)
                                       .frame(width: width * perfectProgress)
                               }
                       }
                   }
               }.frame(height: 1.4).padding(.horizontal)
           }
           .rotation3DEffect(
               angle(proxy),
               axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0),
               anchor: proxy.frame(in: .global).minX > 0 ? .leading : .trailing,
               perspective: 2.5
           )
           .onReceive(timer) { _ in
               let degree = angle(proxy).degrees
               if timerProgress < CGFloat(bundle.stories.count) {
                   if degree == .zero {
                       timerProgress += 0.03
                   }
               } else if degree == .zero && storyData.showStory {
                   updateStory()
               }
           }
       }
       .onAppear {
           timerProgress = 0
       }
       .task {
           try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.3))
           timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
       }
       .onDisappear {
           timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
       }
   }
   func updateStory(forward: Bool = true) {
       Task {
           let index = min(Int(timerProgress), bundle.stories.count - 1)
           let story = bundle.stories[index]
           
           if !forward {
               if let first = storyData.stories.first, first.id != bundle.id {
                   let bundleIndex = self.index(bundle)
                   storyData.isAnimating = true
                   withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                       storyData.currentStory = storyData.stories[bundleIndex - 1].id
                   }
                   try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.3))
                   storyData.isAnimating = false
               } else {
                   timerProgress = 0
               }
           } else if let last = bundle.stories.last, last.id == story.id {
               if let lastBundle = storyData.stories.last, lastBundle.id == bundle.id {
                   withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                       storyData.showStory = false
                   }
               } else {
                   let bundleIndex = self.index(bundle)
                   storyData.isAnimating = true
                   withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                       storyData.currentStory = storyData.stories[bundleIndex + 1].id
                   }
                   try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.3))
                   storyData.isAnimating = false
               }
           }
       }
   }
   func angle(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> Angle {
       let progress = proxy.frame(in: .global).minX / proxy.size.width
       let rotationAngle: CGFloat = 45
       let degrees = rotationAngle * progress
       return Angle(degrees: Double(degrees))
   }
   func index(_ bundle: StoryBundle) -> Int {
       return storyData.stories.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == bundle.id }) ?? 0
   }
}



//  NOT IMPORTANT IGNORE -------


class StoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var stories : [StoryBundle] = [
       StoryBundle(stories: [
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"),
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"),
       ]),
       
       StoryBundle(stories: [
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://pixlr.com/images/index/ai-image-generator-three.webp"),
       ]),
       
       StoryBundle(stories: [
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://pixlr.com/images/index/ai-image-generator-three.webp"),
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
       ]),
       StoryBundle(stories: [
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://pixlr.com/images/index/ai-image-generator-three.webp"),
           StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
       ]),
   ]
   
   @Published var showStory: Bool = false
   @Published var currentStory: String = ""
   @Published var isAnimating: Bool = false
}

struct StoryBundle: Identifiable,Hashable{
   var id = UUID().uuidString
   var stories: [StoryX]
}

struct StoryX: Identifiable,Hashable{
   var id = UUID().uuidString
   var imageURL: String
}

func widthOrHeight(width: Bool) -> CGFloat {
   let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
   let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
   let window = windowScene?.windows.first
   
   if width {
       return window?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
   } else {
       return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
   }
}

#Preview(body: {
   StoryViewXX()
})

